# Clementine didn't run and not showing icon

Tags: 18.04, snap, clementine

I have installed clementine from snapcraft.io with command line `sudo snap install clementine`, and I tried gui also from Ubuntu Store. After installing clementine just shows like this : [image: My Screenshot for clementine icon]

Clementine won't start when I click.

Comment: In a terminal, enter "clementine" and see if you get any relevant error messages.

Comment: Command 'clementine' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install clementine  # version 1.3.1.36+git, or
sudo apt  install clementine

See 'snap info clementine' for additional versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used `sudo apt install clementine`, you did not install from snap but from Ubuntu repositories.

The correct command for snap is `snap install clementine`

I've tried with snap install on my Xubuntu and got an error similar to yours so the available snap might encounter an issue right now. So you probably indeed installed from snap.

You can uninstall Clementine for now and retry later:

```
snap remove clementine
```

And/or you can install the version from Ubuntu repositories with the command you gave:

```
sudo apt install clementine
```

This version works for me.

Comment: I mean snap install clementine, im so sorry with that.